# Output plm result with tab_model error:undefined columns selected

Tags: r, output, fixed, plm, sjplot

Good morning guys, I try to use tab_model(package:sjPlot) output my plm result, but encounter this error

Error in `[.data.frame`(mf, , model_terms, drop = FALSE) : undefined columns selected

The function only works on model with 2&4 independent variables, but error in 1&3 independent variables, still don't know what's going on......

Anyone know how to fix this problem? thanks you guys

Comment: which version of sjPlot are you on? I had the issue on the old version. I am on sjPlot_2.8.4 now

Comment: 2.8.4 too, the latest version